# AJAX calls action for a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a page show.html.erb with a corresponding action 'show'. Lower on the page, a partial is loaded called _filter.html.erb which contains undefined instances (so basically, on the initial load, nothing is displayed there).

In the show.html.erb, I have a form that uses AJAX and submits to an action called "filter" which is supposed to create some instances for use within the _filter partial (so now, the _filter partial within show will have some content).

But when i submit the form, it says `Template is missing  Missing template results/filter`.

But what it should be doing is staying on the same current template (show.html.erb) and just run the filter action and update the partial _fitler.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Following some things i found online, i made a file _filter.js.erb withing the views/results directory (same dir as show.html.erb and _filter.html.erb):

```
$("filter").update("<%= escape_javascript(render("filter"))%>");
```

But it doesnt seem to be doing anything..

Answer (score 0):

By rails convention if you use the name `_filter` then you should put this file in `shared` folder.

So it's should be `shared/_filter.html.erb`

Comment: Why? Because its a partial or bc the name filter?

Comment: Because it's a partial. The sign '_' means that rails should look for this file in 'shared' folder.