# Change jQuery to Prototype?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototypejs

Im trying to use AJAX to update a partial on a page. I following tutorials online and realized one thing, the .js.erb file im using contains jQuery code, while my app is set up to use Prototype. Can the .js.erb file contain Prototype code, or only jQuery? Can this code be written in Prototype?

filter.js.erb:

```
$("#filter").update("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "filter")).html_safe %>");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm unsure of what the .update() method does, but it seems that you are only rendering the content of "filter" inside an element with an ID of filter. 
Actually it seems that the .update method is from Prototype and not jQuery http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/update/ ? So there is no jQuery going in your page (Prototype ALSO uses the $, so you could be confused thinking it was jQuery).

Comment: @LEOPiC Right, but the tricky part is that the <div id="filter"> is inside the show.html.erb, and the filter action shouldn't have its own view, it should just run when a form is submitted on show .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179758/ajax-calls-action-for-a-partial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the version of Rails you have, you probably need the JS adapter (https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)

You can use jQuery code if you include the jquery.js in one of your templates, but to use the Rails specific javascript features, you'll need to setup the adapter.

As far as I know, it's an either/or proposition for Rails-UJS.
Both jQuery & Prototype support "no-conflict" modes, but Rails cannot do unobtrusive javascript using both libraries at the same time.